# find radiobuttonlist in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How can I find radiobuttonlist and it's items in gridview?
Gridview code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="20px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_NIU" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" BorderColor="Transparent">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="N" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="I" Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="U" Value="3" ></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>                                
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and .vb code:

```
Protected Sub gvImport_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvImport.RowDataBound
        'Dim radio As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("rbl_NIU"), RadioButtonList)
        'Dim radio As RadioButtonList = TryCast(sender, RadioButtonList)
        Dim radio As RadioButtonList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("rbl_NIU"), RadioButtonList)
        For Each par As Paraugs In list
            For Each item As RadioButton In radio.Items
                par.Write.ToString()
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

I have tried everything but every time I get "object reference not set to an instance of an object" in "For Each item" and On break-point "radio" returns "Nothing"

Where is the problem? Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: where is `list` defined?

Comment: What is the type of e.Row.RowType? (must be a DataControlRowType.DataRow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the `gvImport.RowDataBound` this will still count headers, so you need a quick if statement at the top of the Sub:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
'Look for radio button list in this
End If
```